# Should I delete this Q?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question showed a lack of research](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/62198/can-we-weaponize-the-helvetica-scenario) - I looked up the premise quickly, got what I needed, and posted it - and the comments and answer have made it clear to me that the question is very much at fault.

I accept that I am very much wrong and I plan to look into things like this more in the future before I post questions - but I am now ready for this one to be gone.

It does not provide information that can help any other users as it's based off of a false premise - pseudoscience - for the sake of a fiction story. I am willing to keep the changes in reputation from the Q (if that happens) but I want to remove the question itself.

Assuming the answerer is willing to remove their answer,
**Is it worth deleting this question?**

Comment: I think that "knowing the question to be wrong" is valuable knowledge.

Comment: On the other hand, if you delete your post now that it is at -3, you can get the peer pressure badge...

Comment: @kingledion That sounds great actually, could you remove your answer on it so that I can delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be that rather than trying to delete the question instead you rephrase it so that it fits the given answer.

This is not advice I've given before and would not like to set it as a precedent. Generally we are opposed to radically changing the question but in this case I think it is appropriate. You have now realized you asked the wrong question, someone has answered the question you would have asked if you realized. By making the change you do not invalidate their answer and save everyone the work of copying and pasting the Q&A into a new question or just deleting everything and wasting what has been done.

Simply change your question to be a reality check and say you are thinking of using this effect in your world. Then you can ask if this effect is real, compatible with known science, or completely implausible.

The resulting Q&A are now helpful for anyone else who has seen this mentioned somewhere and thinking of using it when Worldbuilding. The existing answer is not invalidated, and you should stop accumulating down votes and maybe even get some up votes.

Comment: I think it may be too late to get helpful answers (or upvotes) but I appreciate the help nonetheless. I'll probably delete it as the community still hasn't really found a use for that question and get the peer pressure badge.